# How to draw a line on top of another one in Canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas

I have the necessary coordinates to draw a simple line (x1/y1, x2/y2):

```
canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, paint);
```

Here is the result:

[image: simple line]

The next step I want to draw a second line on top of the existing one:

[image: second lune]

I don't know its coordinates, but the two quantities are known:

1. The distance from start of the black line to the beginning of the red line;
2. The distance from the end of the black line to the end of the red line.

How do I find the coordinates of the red line to draw it? Does the Canvas has built-in tools to draw lines on top of the other? I would be grateful for any clues.

Thank you.

Comment: This is more of a math question than a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to calculate slope of this. Slope of Black and Red line will be same.
Formula for slope is 
   slope = (y2 - y1)/(x2-x1)  then from slope you can check if two points come on that line. But in your case by using slope you will have one equation for y2-y1 but you need another equation also to find these unknown. This link will give you some hint about you problem.
http://www.coolmath.com/algebra/08-lines/06-finding-slope-line-given-two-points-01

Answer (score 0):

The Co-Ordinates of the 2nd line will be 
x1 of red = x1 of black + distance you know (1).
x2 of red = x2 of black - distance you know (2).

1 and 2 are the two quantities that you have.

May be try using another paint with same y values... and above x values

Comment: Yes, the problem is how to determine the Y-co-ordinates of the red line.